# What is current_ability in CanCan's accessible_by (fetching records)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, authorization, cancan

In the documentation of CanCan it shows [how to fetch all accessible records](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/fetching-records) in this way:

```
@articles = Article.accessible_by(current_ability)
```

but what is `current_ability`? I've tried passing the current user which I'm using for authentication and authorization, but I've got this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `conditions' for #<User:0x1092a3b90>
```

Any ideas what should I pass to `accessible_by` or what's wrong here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

CanCan extends `ActionController::Base` with the `current_ability` method (among others), which is the class that your `ApplicationController` should inherit from. So the example code in your question should work as is.

Comment: You can also pass in your own ability using an instance of the ability class you've defined. The ability class is the one that include's CanCan::Ability, and you can use it like so: Ability.new(current_user)

Comment: i guess many people asked themselves this question. maybe the wiki documentation should be updated?